# Kubernetes service account tokens

Tags: kubernetes

Does anyone know if this change https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/72179 will affect the service account tokens and their ability not to expire? Right now we have such tokens in our CI/CD and we rely that these will not expire.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/72179#issuecomment-504684446)

> This only changes the source of the credentials used by the controller loops started by the kube-controller-manager process. Existing use of tokens retrieved from secrets is not affected.